# Volume of an allowed phase space and integration over it

Tags: integration, volume

Consider 
$$
\Omega_N:=\left\{0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\ldots\leq x_N\leq L;~0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq\ldots\leq y_N\leq L\right\}.
$$

It is said that the volume of $\Omega_N$ is
$$
V_N=V(\Omega_N)=L^{2N}/(N!)^2.
$$

How to see this?

Moreover, it is said that any integration over $\Omega_N$ may be replaced by an integration of the symmetrized integrand over $L^{2N}$ and multiplication of the result by $(N!)^{-2}$,

> > $$
> > \int_{\Omega_N}f(C_N)dx^Ndy^N=\frac{1}{(N!)^2}\int_{L^{2N}}f_{\text{sym}}(C_N)dx^N dy^N.
> > $$
> >     where $C_N$ are configurations.

I do not understand that. Do you have any idea how to get this? I literally have *no* idea.

Comment: The volume is $(\int_{0}^{L}dx_{N}\int_{0}^{x_{N}}dx_{N-1}\cdots\int_{0}^{x_{2}}dx_{1})\cdot (\int_{0}^{L}dy_{N}\int_{0}^{y_{N}}dy_{N-1}\cdots\int_{0}^{y_{2}}dy_{1})$. Each factor equals $L^{N}/N!$.

Comment: @studiosus Why, how do you get this?

Comment: The volume is $\int_{\Omega_{N}} dx_{1}dx_{2} \cdots dx_{N}dy_{1}dy_{2} \cdots dy_{N}$. Now plug in the bounds for each variable: $x_{N}$ runs from $0$ to $L$, $x_{N-1}$ runs from $0$ to $x_{N}$,...,$x_{1}$ runs from $0$ to $x_{2}$. Similarly for the $y_{i}$.